# How to find message's file unique IDs with Telegram bot API?

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot

i'm experimenting with Golang Telegram bot APIs and I have a problem with the ID of the message's file that i send to the bot.

I forwarded a message of type VOICE to the bot and in the code I read the unique ID of this file to understand if the bot received that voice message yet (... maybe forwarded by another user).

The problem is that when I read the ID with this code `msg.Voice.FileID` I get always a different string. But not completely different, the first and last part of the string is always the same, but the middle part changes, like this:

> id first time i forward the message: **aaaaaa_abc_zzzzz**
>
> id second time i forward the message: **aaaaaa_def_zzzzz**

The doc does not say anything about it... (https://godoc.org/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api)

Do you guys know how to deal with file ids? My goal is to be able to say "ok, I received this photo (or voice, or audio, or video) yet from this or another user"

Thank you for your time

Ve

Comment: What about hashing the content of the files instead of using their ids? That way you could also check for duplicate content

Comment: I initially thought about that as well and you're right. But i hope there is a better way, because downloading the files and hashing them every time would be really time consuming...

Answer (score 2):

As a reddit user pointed out [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TelegramBots/comments/ft1vf9/how_to_get_unique_ids_of_messages_files/fm4jwry?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x), it is possibile to have the unique id of a file as per v4.5 of the Telegram API https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#december-31-2019.

I couldn'd find that out because a was reading the Golang implementation [godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api) and the "unique id" feature is not yet implemented.

I'm going to add it and make a PR.